# Problems downloading files in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, home-networking, mp3

I have some files that are stored on an external cdn. URLs look like this:

http://cdn.example.com/whatever/whatever_10.mp3

These files are about 450MB in size.

When I try to download these files on my Windows 10 PC only a few Bytes are downloaded. Chrome just stops without any message, Firefox tells me "the source cannot be read"

When putting the traffic through fiddler I have the following warning:

```
Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 155.228.005 bytes, but server sent 548.585 bytes.
```

Accessing the same file from the same network with another device (smartphone) works just fine, so this should not be the server's nor the router's fault.

On the other hand: Other big files, even a few GB like MSDN-ISOs work fine on my Windows PC, too, what does look like Windows is not the reason for this, either.

If Windows is not the cause of the problem and the Network/Server isn't either: What could cause this behavior?

Update: Same Network, Windows 8: No Problems

Update(2): Tried with .zip - file. Same problem

Update(3): Response Headers sent by Server when trying to download zip:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.11
Date: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 20:39:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Length: 155228005
Connection: keep-alive
Last-Modified: Fri, 28 Oct 2016 20:20:27 GMT
ETag: "5813b30b-9409765"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="blathering_010.zip"
X-Clacks-Overhead: GNU Terry Pratchett
X-Cache-Status: MISS
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Update(4): Another user with Windows 10 has the same issues with this server

Comment: If you change the extension of the file what happens?  You are using "Save link as..." correct?

Comment: I save by just entering the URL into the browser's address. To the first part: I currently have no access to the server to rename/upload under a different suffix. Will have to try that on monday

Comment: is there a proxy server in play? and what if you try another browser? I've searched for your 312 message, and almost all the top hits are related to Chrome.

Comment: No Proxy. As I wrote: Tested on FireFox & Chrome

Comment: @Frank Thomas "312" is just the ID inside Fiddler this time, not a status code